# Lighthouse Graphql use model without migrated table

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-8, laravel-lighthouse

Today I stumbled against an issue. Basically I want to use two tables from database, do some calculations on a method and then return it as a `Type`. However I get error, I don't need to store it anywhere, it should be temporary, just to send information to front-end. I'm trying to use`NormalWorkHours` and `OverrideWorkHours` tables to get one table of information. I'm trying to create model instance and send that data or should I use String, json or something else?
So here's my `WorkHours` model:

```
    class WorkHours extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Uuids;

    protected $fillable = [
        'dayofweek',
        'open_time',
        'close_time',
        'timezone',
    ];

    public function restaurant()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Restaurant::class);
    }
}
```

This is Restaurant model:

```
 class Restaurant extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Uuids;
        /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'selected'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(RestaurantCategory::class);
    }
    public function address()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Address::class);
    }
    public function normalWorkHours()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(NormalWorkHours::class);
    }
    public function overrideWorkHours()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OverrideWorkHours::class);
    }

    public function getWorkHours()
    {
        // $workHours = new WorkHours(
        //     [
        //         'dayofweek' => $this->normalWorkHours[0]->dayofweek,
        //         'open_time' => $this->normalWorkHours[0]->open_time,
        //         'close_time' => $this->normalWorkHours[0]->close_time,
        //         'timezone' => $this->normalWorkHours[0]->timezone,
        //     ]
        // );

        $workHours = new WorkHours;
        $workHours->dayofweek = $this->normalWorkHours[0]->dayofweek;
        $workHours->open_time = $this->normalWorkHours[0]->open_time;
        $workHours->close_time = $this->normalWorkHours[0]->close_time;
        $workHours->timezone = $this->normalWorkHours[0]->timezone;

        return $workHours;
    }

}
```

I haven't done the logic, calculations yet, just testing out. I'm trying to create new object of `WorkHours` and return it as an object in graphql. But I get error:

```
"debugMessage": "User Error: expected iterable, but did not find one for field Restaurant.getWorkHours."
```

This is my Restaurant type in graphql:

```
type Restaurant {
id: ID!
user_id: ID!
name: String!
selected: Boolean
image_path: String
created_at: DateTime!
updated_at: DateTime!

user: User! @belongsTo
category: [RestaurantCategory!] @belongsToMany
ingredients: [Ingredient] @hasMany 
additions: [AdditionsCollection!] @hasMany 
alergens: [Alergens] @hasMany 
extraIngredients: [ExtraIngredients] @hasMany 
mealSizes: [MealSize!] @hasMany 
sauces: [Sauces!] @hasMany  
address: Address! @hasOne
normalWorkHours: [NormalWorkHours] @hasMany
overrideWorkHours: [OverrideWorkHours] @hasMany
# getWorkhours: WorkHours @method(name: "getWorkHours")
getWorkHours: [WorkHours] @method
}
```

I also have type of `WorkHours` in graphql.

```
type WorkHours {
dayOfWeek: Int @rename(attribute: "dayofweek")
openTime: String @rename(attribute: "open_time")
closeTime: String @rename(attribute: "close_time")
timezone: Int
closed: Boolean!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema says `Restaurant.getWorkHours` will return a list, but your method only returns a single object - thus the error message:

```json
"debugMessage": "User Error: expected iterable, but did not find one for field Restaurant.getWorkHours."
```

Comment: Sorry, couldn't answer earlier, but yea I just realised this was such a stupid mistake, thank you! It works perfect now.